# What is the real range of dpi for screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I want to know the screen size of an Android phone (without using code)

For example: I find that from specs someone has a device with `1080 x 1920 pixels (~445 ppi pixel density)`
How would I go from here to figure out which layout his or her phone will support?

From this [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), I got:

```
lpdi = 120 DPI
mdpi = 160 DPI
hdpi = 240 DPI
xhdpi = 320 DPI
xxhdpi = 480 DPI
xxxhdpi = 640 DPI
```

And this rough estimation below which seems so ridiculous.

[image]

Where does the DPI fall, if it is 215 for example?

I want to know the layout size to choose for a particular device that I don't own:

Whether the layout be should be **small**, **medium**, **large**, or **extra large** ?

Comment: I converted my comments into an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion between dpi and ppi.
The correct term should be ppi, but it's dpi by convention.

So, **roughly**, we can assume that `ppi = dpi`, for our purposes.

For your reference: http://www.fastcodesign.com/3039564/the-difference-between-ppi-vs-dpi-explained-by-a-google-designer

445 ppi falls in the 480 dpi normalized bucket. 215 ppi falls in the 240 dpi normalized bucket.

I used the term "bucket" improperly: I should have said "range", to be more clear.

How would I calculate the ranges?

I'd say that the range starts from the median between (320 and 480) + 1 and ends at the median between 480 and 640.
Therefore, for the 480 "bucket", I calculate a range between 401 and 560. And 445 falls here into.

Note: it's all empyrical.

The proposed figure on the Android developers site is a poor representation of the concept.
I prefer to imagine those buckets like adjacent funnels with a "mouth" which is 160 dpi wide and an end which points to a normalized value.

Here's an image I prepared just to make it even more clear:

[image]

Comment: I came across an unusual case where I see this [device](http://imgur.com/TW0bPsq) in AVD is `240x432` at 3.4 inch which has PPI of 145 if you calculate. This should fall into "mdpi" according to the range but it is labelled as "ldpi",

Comment: How is the ppi calculated? Anyway, my "ruleset" is really empyrical. Maybe it's 146 instead of 141. To be considered is the form factor: "long". A "normal" ldpi phone usually has a resolution of 240*320 (QVGA). While a common mdpi resolution was 320*480 (HVGA). This device is "something in between" two standard resolutions with their usual densities.

Comment: There's a formula for that `sqrt(W^2+H^2 )/Diagonal` Maybe there is a programmatical way to confirm the range for ldpi and see if it matches the ruleset?

Comment: If you're into mathematics, I found some on this [page](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android). I don't know how relevant it is, bit maybe it's worth a read.

Comment: I forgot to clarify the real question that was actually intended in the question. After I have the density, how would you check the screen size? For example: You have 1080x1920 that is 5.2 or 3.95 inch with xxhdpi. now I want to know where its screen is small, medium, large, or extra large (xlarge) etc so I can pick a layout.

Comment: Aww... this is a real overkill. You really should not do all this work in your app. Once you set the most used folders for phones and those for tables (which are different!), you should be good to run your app on most devices. If a user has a particular device which needs a fix, then publish an update.

Comment: Yes, it seems I am overthinking about it. I don't think this part is even documented that you should start with particular layout. Generally, from what I know is that a small layout will scale automatically all the screens and you can tweak it further if needed.

Comment: Yes, right. The "small layout" is an mdpi screen. Which is considered to be the "normal" density (for the times when they defined the standard). By using `dp` (for drawables) and `sp` (for text), you should be fine. Now that we have VectorDrawables, it's even easier to get properly scaled layouts.